# redmine gives 404 error after installation

Tags: debian, nginx, installation, http-status-code-404, redmine

I am using Debian squeeze with nginx and mysql. After raking db and loading default data to redmine. When i try to visit redmine in a browser, `http://ipaddress:8080/redmine`, I get a 404 error

```
Page not found

The page you were trying to access doesn't exist or has been removed.
```

My nginx configuration file, below:

```
server {
    listen      8080;

    server_name  localhost;
    server_name_in_redirect off;


    #charset koi8-r;

    #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

    location / {
        root   html;
        index  index.html index.htm index.php;
    }

    location ^~/phpmyadmin/ {
            root /usr/share/phpmyadmin;
            index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /usr/share/$fastcgi_script_name;
    }


    location /redmine/ {
                root /usr/local/lib/redmine-1.2/public;
                access_log /usr/local/lib/redmine-1.2/log/access.log;
                error_log /usr/local/lib/redmine-1.2/log/error.log;
                passenger_enabled on;
                allow all;
        }

       location ~ \.php$ {
                fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www$fastcgi_script_name;
                include fastcgi_params;
        }

        location /phpMyadmin {
                rewrite ^/* /phpmyadmin last;
        }
```

I don't know what the problem is - this is my second attempt to install redmine in Debian with nginx.

Comment: Check section [Deploying to a sub URI](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html#deploying_rails_to_sub_uri) in Passenger documentation.